# LPLinkview UI Structure issue

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to present a LPlinkView inside a custom view which is a subview of another view which is a subview of UITableview cell.

The UI Structure of the LPLink view I'm getting is:https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn67O.png

But The result I need is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoMkS.png

Is there any way to achieve this??

Comment: Doesn’t the resulting preview depend entirely on the meta tags of the fetched web page? Do you get the small version with all URLs?

Comment: No I get different preview for different URL's.

Comment: So then it sounds like it’s just down to the different meta tags on the different web sites. If they provide images or videos etc to show in the preview.

Comment: I found out what the issue was.Thank you